# Difference between python lambda functions inside class and def

Tags: python, oop, lambda

I have the following code.

```
class SomeClass:

    a = lambda self: self.b()

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = lambda self: None

s = SomeClass()
s.a()
```

It give me "TypeError: () takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)". And I want to understand why.

My explanation:

- a - class method, so `s.a()` equlas `SomeClass.a(s)`
- b - object's attribute (not a method, just a function), that is why `self.b()` doesn't equal `SomeClass.b(self)`

  So in `a = lambda self: self.b()` argument for `b` is missing.

  Am I  right?

  P.S. Is it closure effect?

  ```
  class SomeClass:

      a = lambda self: self.b()

      def __init__(self):
          self.data = 12
          self.b = lambda: self.data

  s = SomeClass()
  print s.a()       #12
  s.data = 24
  print s.a()       #24
  ```

Comment: `a = lambda self: self.b(self)` ? -- although that seems atrociously unreadable (and maybe not correct). Why use `lambda` in a class definition like that?

Comment: @PeterWood That gives another TypeError, you're giving 2 arguments

Comment: @PeterWood: You're wrong. The `self` for `a` is implicitly bound like normal, because `a` is a _method_ defined on the class (doesn't matter if you use `lambda` or `def`, it's still a method, though `def` is preferred for other reasons, e.g. the method knows its own name). It doesn't happen for `b`, because `b` is a _function_ that just happens to be an attribute of the instance, not a method (methods are defined at class definition level, not in instance initializer, you'd need metaprogramming nonsense to make them actual bound methods in the initializer; don't do it).

Comment: If you're ever assigning a lambda to a name, don't use a lambda.  There is no advantage over a def.

Comment: @JohnColeman it's just an interesting for understanding example. Nobody  wants write code in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is the difference between bound methods and functions

Have a simpler example:

```
class Someclass(object):
    bound = lambda *args: "bound method got {}".format(args)
    def __init__(self):
        self.unbound = lambda *args: "function got {}".format(args)
```

```
>>> c = Someclass()
```

If we look closely, these two functions are not of the same type:

```
>>> c.bound
<bound method Someclass.<lambda> of <__main__.Someclass object at 0x...>>
>>> c.unbound
<function Someclass.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x...>
```

And as a result, when we call them, they receive different arguments:

```
>>> c.bound(1, 2, 3)
'bound method got (<__main__.Someclass object at 0x...>, 1, 2, 3)'
>>> c.unbound(1, 2, 3)
'unbound got (1, 2, 3)'
```

Notice that only the "bound" function got a `self` argument passed in.

<sup>Tested in 3.5 - 2.7 might have slightly different names for things</sup>

Comment: On your final note: Actually, 3.5 and 2.7 will agree here. The only point of disagreement is what `Someclass.a``/`Someclass.bound` (accessed on class, not instance) is; in 2.7, it's an "unbound method", in 3.5, it's a plain function (3.5 just has functions and bound methods, no special in-between thing that is "a method waiting to be bound"; accessing a plain function through an instance that is found on the instance's class makes it bind automatically).

Comment: Yep, I realize that this avoids the unbound method problem. Although in py2, the lambda prints as the less informative `<function <lambda> at 0x...>`

Comment: As I undrestand, @Eric 's answer and ShadowRanger 's comment to my question are the same explanations. And I think my ideas were similar to your, but you showed it clearer.
Thank you!

Comment: @Alex: Your example was less clear because one function was calling the other, so there were way more places to be surprised by argument counts. Plus the fact that `self` is still available to `unbound` with a closure anyway

Comment: @Eric , one more question about closure. Are you talking about following behavior?
'class SomeClass:
    
    a = lambda self: self.b()
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 12
        self.b = lambda: self.data
        
s = SomeClass()
print s.a()                  # 12
s.data = 24
print s.a()                 # 24 '

Comment: @Eric , sorry for formatting. Added P.S. into question